# Computer/camera not detecting sd card

Tags: sd-card

I have an SD card that was fine until today. I was able to take pictures on the camera and it loaded fine on the computer.

Then, all of a sudden, the camera gives me a "Memory Card Locked" error. I check the side of the card, but it's in the unlocked position. I also try to insert it into multiple computers, but none of them recognize it. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

SD cards, and generally any flash media in general, have a limited read and write cycle. If NONE of your computers recognize it all, and at least one them used to, the card probably just stopped working.